# Is it possible to re-style a QProgressBar on OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qstyle

The approach using a QStyle Subclass, and setting the palette doesn't work (but does work for other base styles to `MyStyle`).

```
void MyStyle::drawControl(ControlElement control, const QStyleOption *option,
                          QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
{    
    switch(control) 
    {
        case CE_ProgressBar: 
        {
            const QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 * pOpts =
            static_cast<const QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 *>(option);
            QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 oOpts(*pOpts);

            QColor progressColor(QColor::fromHsl(50, 160, 162));
            oOpts.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, progressColor);

            // BASESTYLE is QMacStyle
            BASESTYLE::drawControl(control, &outputOptions, painter, widget);
        }
            break;

        default:
            BASESTYLE::drawControl(control, option, painter, widget);
    }
}
```

Is there some other way to control the appearance of widgets under OS X? (Or is it completely impossible?)

Comment: What do you get if you comment out all of the code in the CE_ProgressBar case?  Does the QProgressBar then draw nothing/garbage only?  If so, that would indicate that you are on the right track, but BASESTYLE::drawControl)( is ignoring your preamble.

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that if `BASESTYLE::drawControl()` in the `CE_ProgressBar` case is removed, then no progress bar is drawn. (`BASESTYLE` is, of course, `QMacStyle`).

Comment: In the worst case you could always copy-and-paste the code from BASESTYLE::drawControl() into your own method, and then modify it to taste... but there may be a more elegant method than that.  You'll have to look at the source code for BASESTYLE::drawControl() and see how the CE_ProgressBar case is implemented, and that should give you some ideas about what influence you can have on its behavior.

Comment: Committing the crime of using a cross platform UI framework on a Mac takes away from you the right to be concerned with style ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [QSS](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet.html), see [QProgressBar example](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-6353d8d9-9de4-4af5-b44e-e3beb567dfea)